# Bash variable substitution when running using JMX on java

Tags: java, spring, bash

I'm trying to use VisualVM with a Spring app. When configuring the ports, this works:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5006 \ 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=5006 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \ 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost \ 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But when cleaning up, I tried this, and that does not work:

```
export JMX="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5006 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=5006 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false"
java $JMX -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The app started, but I could not connect and netstat listed no open port 5006

Everything is the same, except that the long list of parameters is in a variable. If I use this instead of $JAVA_JMX, it works:

```
$(echo "$JMX")
```

Why does regular substitution not work in this case? And there must be a more elegant way to solve this.

demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is just an unmodified spring boot app I downloaded from their starter page.

Comment: Use `JMX` as array variable instead of string variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use it like this using a shell array:

```sh
jmx=(-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5006 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=5006 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false)
java "${jmx[@]}" -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```